# How to make nice openGL blended lines in cocos2d?

Tags: objective-c, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

i've written an algorithm to create electricity using ccDrawLine function in cocos2d for iphone. Currently, the ccDrawLine is a simple wrapper method for drawing openGL lines on the fly.

My algorithm is sound and works as I want. But the problem is with the appearance of the electricity in general.

I have little openGL programming knowledge(hence the use of the wrapper) and I require the ccLines to be blended nicely and look like either lasers or electricity.

How can I go about doing this avoiding the use of openGL programming if possible, otherwise i'll need to learn it.

Comment: i just started ios programming myself but i would recommend just learning openGL. it may seem like a large task but openGL is available in many other languages and learning it would help you in many areas

Comment: Your probably right. How would I do this in OpenGL then? (if you know)

Comment: you sample the surrounding pixels for each pixel of the area and average it out. This is the most basic way i know but it is not very fast so you could blend in 2x2 squares instead of 1x1 or even 4x4 and move over every iteration because for a nice effect you would do maybe 3 times.

Comment: ill just post that as an answer, so if it works give me a +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

you sample the surrounding pixels for each pixel of the area and average it out. This is the most basic way i know but it is not very fast so you could blend in 2x2 squares instead of 1x1 or even 4x4 and move over every iteration because for a nice effect you would do maybe 3 times.

Comment: What do you mean average it out? Do you mean bend the outer pixels of the line with the background or something? I need a little more info :)